# Template class specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I did read some of the related threads but still the issue was not clear:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <> class stack <int>
{
  public:
    std :: vector <int> stackVector;

};
```

The compilation error:

```
templateSpecializ.cpp:5: error: ‘stack’ is not a template
templateSpecializ.cpp:6: error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘stack’
```

From this link: [coderSource.net](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorial-on-templates/c-class-template-specialization.aspx)

Have I missed some point? I feel I have. I even tried to define the functions there, but that was not helpful.

Comment: Why are there extra spaces everywhere in your code (e.g. std :: vector)? If this is on purpose, it won't work, remove them.

Comment: Oh, ok, excuse me, I'd never seen code like that and assumed it wouldn't work.

Comment: With respect to spaces, there is only one thing that I have not found working till now is the *>>* brackets of templates, they need to have a space between them.

Comment: Yes, this is on purpose, otherwise the compiler can not know if you are trying to apply the shift operator (operator>>) or defining the template.

Comment: Off-topic we go:
1) One per day, if I'm not mistaken.
2) Click your username at the top, then click the edit link, change "Display name".

Comment: Sure, hover over a comment, you'll see an up arrow and a flag icon. Click the arrow :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a template specialisation of a template called stack. stack is not defined inany of those header files. If you wish to define a new template class you must first define the base case

```
template<typename T>
class stack
{
  //implementation goes here
};

template<>
class stack<int>
{
 public:
  std::vector<int> stackVector;
};
```

If you wish to only define stack for int and not for every type you can use

```
template<typename T> class stack;
template<>
class stack<int>
{
 public:
  std::vector<int> stackVector;
};
```

Comment: Thanks to you too, now I understand, after I define the base class, I can write the derived classes with many types, your second example was more clear.

Comment: And all this while I used to believe that LinuxQuestions.org is the only helpful site :rolleyes:

Comment: Yes, however you would probably want to define the vector to have the type of whatever type is put into the stack `template <typename T> class stack{public:std::vector <T> stackVector};`

Answer (score 3):

You can not specialize your template if you don't have a template to specialize yet. So this should work:

```
template <typename T>
class stack
{
};

template <>
class stack<int>
{
  public:
    std::vector<int> stackVector;
};
```